# Why is the value of my strcmp not equal to 0 or invalid?

Tags: c

I am still new to programming and there are a lot of things I still don't know but I'd like to ask why my if statement doesn't seem to be working properly. It seems the value
of `strcmp(bookName, tolower(searchedName))` when the variable `searchedName = "introduction to c"` is not 0.
Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  char bookName[30] = "introduction to c programming";
  char searchedName[30];

  printf("Enter the book you are searching for:  ");
  scanf("%s", &searchedName);

  if (strcmp(bookName, tolower(searchedName)) != 0) {
    printf("The book is not in elibrary");
  } else {
    printf("The book is in elibrary");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on warnings when building and you will be given a really big hint or two.

Comment: `tolower(searchedName)` shouldn't compile.

Comment: Hint: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/  (Works on a single character...)

Comment: You don't need `&` in front of `searchedName`. `&` is only used when you need the address of a primitive type.

Comment: because "introduction to c programming" is not the same as "introduction to c"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`tolower()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) is for converting characters, not strings. You will have to apply it to each characters in the string separately.
- You don't need `&` before arrays in this case because arrays in expressions are automatically converted to pointers (except for some case).
- `%s` in `scanf()` will stop at whitespace character. `%[^\n]` is useful to read until hitting a newline character.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  char bookName[30] = "introduction to c programming";
  char searchedName[30];
  char searchedName_lower[30];
  int i;

  printf("Enter the book you are searching for:  ");
  scanf("%[^\n]", searchedName);

  i = 0;
  do {
    searchedName_lower[i] = tolower((unsigned char)searchedName[i]);
  } while (searchedName[i++] != '\0');

  if (strcmp(bookName, searchedName_lower) != 0) {
    printf("The book is not in elibrary");
  } else {
    printf("The book is in elibrary");
  }

  return 0;
}
```